# Linux PAM: Mapping between configuration and application

Tags: linux, pam

I have multiple files in /etc/pam.d. I think they slightly differ in name between different distributions. And I also do not see a direct connection between process-name and configuration (e.g. chpasswd vs. passwd).

Is somewhere or somehow defined which application uses which pam-files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: there's no rule; instead it depends on the implementation done by the application's developer.

**LONG VERSION**:

When a program uses PAM for authentication, it has to call [`pam_start()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_start):

```
int pam_start(const char *service_name, const char *user, const struct pam_conv *pam_conversation, pam_handle_t **pamh);
```

The first argument, `service_name`, is the one used to pick the configuration.

For example, OpenSSH server calls `pam_start()` in its source file `auth_pam.c`:

```
sshpam_err =
    pam_start(SSHD_PAM_SERVICE, user, &store_conv, &sshpam_handle);
```

The constant `SSH_PAM_SERVICE` is defined (in the same file) as follows:

```
#if !defined(SSHD_PAM_SERVICE)
extern char *__progname;
# define SSHD_PAM_SERVICE       __progname
#endif
```

Furthermore, the value of `__progname` is defined in `ssh.c` as:

```
__progname = ssh_get_progname(av[0]);
```

As you may know, `av[0]` in C is the name of the binary. So, if the OpenSSH daemon binary is named `sshd`, `pam_start()` will be called with `sshd` as the `service_name`.

(Note that I ignored the `ssh_get_progname()` call, but I think this is still enough to illustrate my answer.)